# How to print a list in Python "nicely"

Tags: python

In PHP, I can do this:

```
echo '<pre>'
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>'
```

In Python, I currently just do this:

```
print the_list
```

However, this will cause a big jumbo of data. Is there any way to print it nicely into a readable tree? (with indents)?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(the_list)
```

Comment: How ot pretty print to a file?

Comment: Why not just use `import pprint`?

Comment: @clankill3r, then you need to use `pprint.pprint(the_list)` usually it's just a matter of personal preference. I chose to have the extra clutter in the import line in this case.

Comment: @Mawg, you can specify an output stream using `stream=`, the default is stdout. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: It's enabled by default in Ipython REPL

Comment: @clankill3r  `from pprint import pprint` is equivalent to `import pprint.pprint as pprint`  then you use the `pprint` alias as usual.

Comment: If your list elements are long enough to wrap, the output may look better using the width option, as in pprint(the_list, width=100).

Answer (score 93):

Simply by "unpacking" the list in the print function argument and using a newline (\n) as separator.

**print(*lst, sep='\n')**

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'egg']
print(*lst, sep='\n')

foo
bar
spam
egg
```

Comment: Nice but unfortunately only available in Python 3.

Comment: If you really need it in Python 2.7, you could still import the print function from __future__

`from __future__ import print_function`

Thanks for the comment.

Comment: **the `*` is vital**, got me for a sec x)

Comment: IMO in 2021 where Python 3 is the standard, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 45):

A quick hack while debugging that works without having to import `pprint` would be to join the list on `'\n'`.

```
>>> lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'egg']
>>> print '\n'.join(lst)
foo
bar
spam
egg
```

Comment: TypeError when the list contains `None`.

Comment: Easy solution and can be formated like `"list: * {}".format('\n * '.join(lst))

Comment: when your list contains something other then strings you should do `print '\n'.join(map(str, lst))`

Answer (score 23):

You mean something like...:

```
>>> print L
['this', 'is', 'a', ['and', 'a', 'sublist', 'too'], 'list', 'including', 'many', 'words', 'in', 'it']
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
['this',
 'is',
 'a',
 ['and', 'a', 'sublist', 'too'],
 'list',
 'including',
 'many',
 'words',
 'in',
 'it']
>>>
```

...?  From your cursory description, standard library module [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) is the first thing that comes to mind; however, if you can describe example inputs and outputs (so that one doesn't have to learn PHP in order to help you;-), it may be possible for us to offer more specific help!

Answer (score 21):

```python
import json
some_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
print(json.dumps(some_list, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
]
```

Comment: `json.dumps` adds new line characters in my values for some reason..

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

If you need the text (for using with curses for example):

```
import pprint

myObject = []

myText = pprint.pformat(myObject)
```

Then `myText` variable will something alike php `var_dump` or `print_r`. Check the documentation for more options, arguments.

Answer (score 4):

For **Python 3**, I do the same kind of thing as [shxfee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28928248/9526925):

```
def print_list(my_list):
    print('\n'.join(my_list))

a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
print_list(a)
```

which outputs

```
foo
bar
baz
```

As an aside, I use a similar helper function to quickly see columns in a pandas DataFrame

```
def print_cols(df):
    print('\n'.join(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers suggest **pprint** module does the trick. 
Nonetheless, in case of debugging where you might need to put the entire list into some log file, one might have to use pformat method along with module **logging** along with pprint.

```
import logging
from pprint import pformat

logger = logging.getLogger('newlogger')
handler = logging.FileHandler('newlogger.log')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler) 
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

data = [ (i, { '1':'one',
           '2':'two',
           '3':'three',
           '4':'four',
           '5':'five',
           '6':'six',
           '7':'seven',
           '8':'eight',
           })
         for i in xrange(3)
      ]

logger.error(pformat(data))
```

And if you need to directly log it to a File, one would have to specify an output stream, using the stream keyword. [Ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#module-pprint)

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('output.txt', 'wt') as out:
   pprint(myTree, stream=out)
```

See [Stefano Sanfilippo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280534/prettyprint-to-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, `pprint` is a great module that will do what you want. However if you don't want to import it and just want to print debugging output during development, you can approximate its output.

Some of the other answers work fine for strings, but if you try them with a class object it will give you the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, instance found`.

For more complex objects, make sure the class has a `__repr__` method that prints the property information you want:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo - (%r)" % self.bar
```

And then when you want to print the output, simply map your list to the `str` function like this:

```
l = [Foo(10), Foo(20), Foo("A string"), Foo(2.4)]
print "[%s]" % ",\n ".join(map(str,l))
```

outputs:

```
 [Foo - (10),
  Foo - (20),
  Foo - ('A string'),
  Foo - (2.4)]
```

You can also do things like override the `__repr__` method of `list` to get a form of nested pretty printing:

```
class my_list(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "[%s]" % ",\n ".join(map(str, self))

a = my_list(["first", 2, my_list(["another", "list", "here"]), "last"])
print a
```

gives

```
[first,
 2,
 [another,
 list,
 here],
 last]
```

Unfortunately no second-level indentation but for a quick debug it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method from raw python that I use very often!

**The code looks like this:**

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

**output:**

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also loop trough your list:

```
def fun():
  for i in x:
    print(i)

x = ["1",1,"a",8]
fun()
```

Comment: Hello! Please format the code, as it is, it's not easy to follow. Also, global is not meant to be used it that way in python. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function