# How can I produce a nice output of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, gedit

I currently have the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy
from numpy import linalg

A = [[1,2,47,11],[3,2,8,15],[0,0,3,1],[0,0,8,1]]
S = [[113,49,2,283],[-113,0,3,359],[0,5,0,6],[0,20,0,12]]

A = numpy.matrix(A)
S = numpy.matrix(S)

numpy.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True, linewidth=120)
print("S^{-1} * A * S")
print(linalg.inv(S) * A * S)
```

which produces this output:

[image: python output]

**Is there a standard way to produce an output similar to the following? How can I get this output?**

```
[[ -1    -0.33  0  0]
 [  0     1     0  0]
 [  0  -648     4  0]
 [  0     6.67  0  5]]
```

What's different?

- At least two spaces between the last character of column `i` and the first character of column `i+1`, but it might be more if more is needed (NumPy output makes two spaces)
- the dots are aligned (The *are* aligned, but the font setting of `BetterPythonConsole` messes it up)
- No `-0` but `0`
- No `0.` but `0`

**edit**: It seems as if the Python Console, which gets started with gEdits [BetterPythonConsole](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/BetterPythonConsole) plugin does something different than Python, when I start it from terminal.

This is the output as text of the script above

```
moose@pc07:~/Desktop$ python matrixScript.py 
S^{-1} * A * S
[[  -1.     -0.33    0.     -0.  ]
 [   0.     -1.     -0.      0.  ]
 [   0.   -648.      4.     -0.  ]
 [   0.      6.67    0.      5.  ]]
```

With prettyprint:

```
S^{-1} * A * S
matrix([[  -1.  ,   -0.33,    0.  ,   -0.  ],
        [   0.  ,   -1.  ,   -0.  ,    0.  ],
        [   0.  , -648.  ,    4.  ,   -0.  ],
        [   0.  ,    6.67,    0.  ,    5.  ]])
```

This is defenitely worse, but it was worth a try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have read this question (and the answer), but it doesn't provide enough formatting.

Comment: Did you tried `pprint`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523660/how-to-print-a-list-in-python-nicely

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry thanks for the hint. Because of your hint I have executed it from terminal. I have edited my post. I didn't think of a wrong font setting of `BetterPythonConsole`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use numpy 1.8.x you can customize formatting with the `formatter` parameter.
For example, setting:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: 'float: ' + str(x)})
```

All floats would be printed like `float: 3.0`, or `float: 12.6666666666`.

Unfortunately I still have numpy 1.6.1 installed and this option is not provided,
so I'm not able to use it to get your desired output.

Comment: I guess updating my system would be the best option as all other problems in the formating seem to be related to `BetterPythonConsole`.

Comment: Yes, probably the other option would be to write a custom `format` function to be used with numpy arrays. Which may not be too hard to write, but if you want to make it a bit general for possible future uses it's not something you write in 2 minutes.
Hopefully the upgrade will give you other benefits other than this one.