# Python print array with new line

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have a simple array:

```
op = ['Hello', 'Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Night', 'Bye']
```

When i use pprint, i get this output:

```
['Hello', 'Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Night', 'Bye']
```

Is there anyway i can remove the quotes, commas and brackets and print on a seperate line. So that the output is like this:

```
Hello
Good Morning
Good Evening
Good Night
Bye
```

Answer (score 50):

You could [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings with a newline, and print the resulting string:

```
print "\n".join(op)
```

Answer (score 44):

For Python 3, we can also use list unpack
https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

```
print(*op, sep='\n')
```

It's the same as

```
print('Hello', 'Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Night', 'Bye', sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a couple points of clarification

1. First of all what you have there is a `list`, not an array. The difference is that the list is a far more dynamic and flexible data structure (at list in dynamic languages such as python). For instance you can have multiple objects of different types (e.g have 2 `string`s, 3 `int`s, one `socket`, etc)
2. The quotes around the words in the list denote that they are objects of type `string`.
3. When you do a `print op`  (or `print(op)` for that matter in python 3+) you are essentially asking python to show you a printable representation of that specific list object and its contents. Hence the quotes, commas, brackets, etc.
4. In python you have a very easy `for each` loop, usable to iterate through the contents of iterable objects, such as a `list`. Just do this:

   ```py
   for greeting in op: 
        print greeting
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Print it line by line

```
for word in op:
    print word
```

This has the advantage that if `op` happens to be massively long, then you don't have to create a new temporary string purely for printing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get some nicer print behavior by using the **Pretty Print** library [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

Pretty print will automatically wrap printed contents when you go over a certain threshold, so if you only have a few short items, it'll display inline:

```py
from pprint import pprint
xs = ['Hello', 'Morning', 'Evening']
pprint(xs)
# ['Hello', 'Morning', 'Evening']
```

But if you have a lot of content, it'll auto-wrap:

```py
from pprint import pprint
xs = ['Hello', 'Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Night', 'Bye', 'Aloha', 'So Long']
pprint(xs)
# ['Hello',
#  'Good Morning',
#  'Good Evening',
#  'Good Night',
#  'Bye',
#  'Aloha',
#  'So Long']
```

You can also specify the column width with the `width=` param.

**See Also**: [How to print a list in Python "nicely"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1523660/1366033)