# Prettyprint to a file?

Tags: python, hash, dictionary, tree, pretty-print

I'm using this [gist's](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250/) tree, and now I'm trying to figure out how to prettyprint to a file.  Any tips?

Comment: Is the output format somewhat relevant (other than being properly formatted)?

Comment: Same way you'd write anything else to a file, no?

Comment: @Stefano There are multiple keys and values, which should be clear in the format.

Comment: @MattBall If I printed it with a .write(), the output would essentially be all one line-utterly unreadable.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

What you need is Pretty Print [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module:

```
from pprint import pprint

# Build the tree somehow

with open('output.txt', 'wt') as out:
    pprint(myTree, stream=out)
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, it seems you need to pass stream in the constructor of pprint.PrettyPrinter() like so `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(stream=open("thing",'w'))`

Comment: Not working with Python 3.6.5. The output is a list not a graph which is pretty printed on the screen.

Comment: Worked for me with Python 3.7.2.

Comment: Works fine for me in python 3.9 as well

Answer (score 12):

Another general-purpose alternative is Pretty Print's `pformat()` method, which creates a pretty string.  You can then send that out to a file.  For example:

```
import pprint
data = dict(a=1, b=2)
output_s = pprint.pformat(data)
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(output_s)
```

Comment: Great, thanks, although I prefer: `with open('output.txt','w') as output: output.write(pprint.pformat(data))`

Comment: @Andrew - Absolutely! A good context block is always the best choice! I will update my answer to make it a better programming example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to provide the file to the `stream` keyword on [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint):

```py
from pprint import pprint

with open(outputfilename, 'w') as fout:
    pprint(tree, stream=fout, **other_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
outf = open("./file_out.txt", "w")
PP = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4,stream=outf)
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
PP.pprint(d)
outf.close()
```

Could not get the stream= in the accepted answer to work without this syntax in Python 3.9. Hence the new answer. You could also improve on using the `with` syntax to improve on this too.

```
import pprint
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
with open('./test2.txt', 'w+') as out:
    PP = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4,stream=out)
    PP.pprint(d)
```