# pprint to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import mailbox
import pprint
mbox = mailbox.mbox('c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\mail\mailall.mbox')
for msg in mbox:
pprint.pprint(msg._headers)
```

This prints out hundreds of emails headers one after another. How can i write these results to a txt file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of:

1. Use the `stream` parameter of [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint.pprint)
2. Use [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint.pformat) and separate write operation(s)
3. Redirect the program's output

Comment: This is a bad answer, you have just linked to a bunch of docs and not included any examples, please try and be more helpful in the future as this is next to useless :) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17280610/7469725) is much better as you can clearly see the provided example, please try and do this in the future

Comment: @kopo222 the provided options are trivial enough to not need examples. If someone needs an example on how to add a parameter to a function call, they're probably on a wrong site...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a file output stream.

```
import mailbox
import pprint
f=open('./headersfile.txt', 'w+')
mbox = mailbox.mbox('c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\mail\mailall.mbox')
for msg in mbox:
    pprint.pprint(msg._headers, stream=f)
f.close()
```

Details here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint

Comment: Its giving me an undefined error when i try and open the txt file. the path is correct?

Comment: Hm... You are using Windows, right? Try to use just a file name ("headersfile.txt") or a full path to a file ('c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\headersfile.txt').