# Array not printing properly Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost


charm = Item("Charm of Capitalism", 20)
talis = Item("Talisman of Truth", 100)
shopArray = [charm, talis]

print("Items for sale: {}" .format(shopArray))
```

When I print the shopArray the output is

`Items for sale: [<__main__.Item object at 0x02174270>, <__main__.Item object at 0x021742B0>]`

I want it to display what items are in the shopArray

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Add a `__repr__` method to the `Item` class.

Comment: List is printing object as you have not defined __repr__

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr

Comment: Possible help from this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1523660/3991696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost

    def __repr__(self):
        return "name: " + self.name + " cost: " + str(self.cost)


charm = Item("Charm of Capitalism", 20)
talis = Item("Talisman of Truth", 100)
shopArray = [charm, talis]

print("Items for sale: {}" .format(shopArray))
```

You can define how you want your object look like using `__repr__`.
I hope it resolves your question.

Comment: This answer worked. Thank you

Comment: @DanielGratton welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, `__repr__` should return an string that can be evaluated into code that instantiates an equivalent object. For reading purposes, you should use the `Item.__str__` method:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost

    def __str__(self):
        # Whichever formating you want.
        return '%s: %f' % (self.name, self.cost)


charm = Item("Charm of Capitalism", 20)
talis = Item("Talisman of Truth", 100)
shopArray = [charm, talis]

print("Items for sale: {}" .format(map(str, shopArray)))
```

Notice that you need to map the list of `Items` to `strs`.