# How can I implement .prettify() (BS4) into my function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a function which returns a list like below:

```
['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4']
```

I have tried numerous ways of implementing the soup.prettify() function to pretty print my list. However can't figure out the exact arrangement to make this work.

Below is my function:

```
def get_titles(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    outcome = soup.div.find_all(text=True)
    return(outcome)
```

Calling the function:

```
html = '#the example html'
print(get_titles(html))
```

Again, the current outcome (not exact, just an example of the list):

```
['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4']
```

For clarity, i'm looking to utilise .prettify() to make the outcome list easier to read and therefore 'prettier'.

Comment: something like print('\n'.join(get_titles(html)))?

Comment: you pretiffy a `bs4.Tag` (like your `soup`)  object not a list

Comment: I tried to print using the following  " print(soup.prettify(get_event_titles(html)) " but receive the error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: `pretiffy` needs `bs4 object`, not `list`. With `list` you have to use standard function to format data - like `"\n".join(list)`  or module `pprint` (PrettyPrint) and `pprint.pprint(list)`

Comment: 12 years old question: [How to print a list in Python "nicely" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523660/how-to-print-a-list-in-python-nicely)

Comment: Please add your desired output format to your question

Answer (score 2):

`.pretiffy()` needs `bs4 object`, not `list`.

Standard method to make list more readable is to convert to string using `.join()` with `\n` between elements.

```
print("\n".join(['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4']))
```

Result:

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
```

There is also standard module [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) (`PrettyPrint`) which can format some data

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4'], width=20)
```

Result:

```
['Title 1',
 'Title 2',
 'Title 3',
 'Title 4']
```

You may also use standard module `json` to format data
(but this works only with standard data types - like `list`, `dict`, but not `class`)

```
import json

print(json.dumps(['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4'], indent=2))
```

Result:

```
[
  "Title 1",
  "Title 2",
  "Title 3",
  "Title 4"
]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Of course you can also write own function to display list
(but this will not prettify nested elements/lists/dictionares)

```
def show_list(data):
    print('[')
    print('  ' + ",\n  ".join(f'"{x}"' for x in data) + ',')
    print(']')
   

data = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4']
show_list(data)
```

Result:

```
[
  "Title 1",
  "Title 2",
  "Title 3",
  "Title 4",
]
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is also nice module [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) which also has function `pprint()` and it can use colors to display different type of data

```
from rich.pretty import pprint

data = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 
        1234, {'A':'Hello', 'B':'World', 'C':'Python'}]

pprint(data, expand_all=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Image from page [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich):

[image]